# alternative for Not Like Operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to exclude user accounts which ends with '`_test`' in table1.
I use

```
select * from table1 Not Like '%_test'.
```

But this query doesn't work as expected.

Comment: It doesn't even compile I think? Please be clear and very specific - *never* say "does not work" which can mean a thousand things and therefore means nothing.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `WHERE` from your code snippet, also can you post your error message

Comment: `_` is a LIKE wildcard.

Comment: Apart from the missing `WHERE`, which will cause a syntax error, what isn't working as expected in the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and `NOT LIKE`. `%` and `_` are [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). You asked to exclude rows that end with `test` and at least one character before that, any character.

If you want to use a wildcard as a literal character, [you need to escape it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals)  :

```
select * from table1
where SomeField not like '%[_]test'
```

Given this table :

```
declare @table1 table (somefield varchar(100))

insert into @table1
values
('abc'),
('test'),
('atest'),
('ab_test'),
('_test')
```

The following query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM @table1
WHERE someField NOT LIKE '%[_]test'
```

Returns :

```
somefield
---------
abc
test
atest
```

The *original* query would return :

```
somefield
---------
abc
test
```

Because `%_test` would match `atest`

**UPDATE**

The query returns empty fields or fields that contain spaces without any modification . Given this :

```
declare @table1 table (ID int identity,somefield varchar(100))

insert into @table1
values
('abc'),
('test'),
('atest'),
('ab_test'),
('_test'),
(''),
(' '),
(null)

SELECT *
FROM @table1
WHERE someField not LIKE '%[_]test'
```

The results are :

```
ID  somefield
1   abc
2   test
3   atest
6   
7
```

`NULL` isn't just a blank. In SQL `NULL` means Unknown and any comparison with it results in an `Unknown` value as well. Even `NOT UNKNOWN` results in `UNKNOWN`. This means that neither `LIKE`, nor `NOT LIKE` can match a NULL value. The query would have to explicitly add an `OR SomeField IS NULL` clause to return the `NULL` :

```
SELECT *
FROM @table1
WHERE someField not LIKE '%[_]test' 
    OR somefield is null
```

This returns :

```
ID  somefield
1   abc
2   test
3   atest
6   
7    
8   NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in few cases someField  is blank I want to include them also because in that row other fields are available except someField, currently it shows only if there is data and removes the one's which are blank

Comment: @JP. what does `blank` mean? Empty string, whitespace or NULL? They aren't the same thing. The query will return empty and whitespace fields. Comparing *anything* with NULL returns NULL, which means comparisons fail whether you use `NOT` or not. You'd have to add `OR someField is NULL` to cover NULLs. Update the *question* and post what you want, including sample data and the desired output.

Comment: We are combining 2 tables in that in table1 the Username column is blank and in table 2 when we add the condition someField NOT LIKE '%[_]test' then it also removes the blank columns, I want to include even if they are blank.

Comment: @JP. I'd have to write the same comment again. `blank` means nothing. Post the data and results. Use `OR IS NULL` to include nulls. The query *already* returns whitespace or empty strings

Answer (score 0):

In your query, there is not WHERE keyword and the column name on which you want to check the 'like' condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE
[AccountColumn] NOT LIKE '%[_]test'
```